# Bash script quits after command

Tags: bash

My bash script quits after running the first command, why? It outputs the result of ntpstats and stops

```
#!/bin/bash

# Output ntpstats
ntpstats

echo ""

# Output ntp query
ntpq -p
```

Comment: Probably it just prints the output from `ntpq -p`.
Can you verify every command by running it manually?

Comment: Have you tried to run the script with `bash -x`? It shows something useful information for debugging perhaps.